# Unable To Convert PDF file to Text using IronOCR dll

Tags: c#, iis, ocr

Am Using a nuget library called IronOCR to convert a pdf file to Text.

Below is the Code for that,

```
public ActionResult GetFileText(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                filepath = Server.MapPath(filepath);

                string[] tokens = filepath.Split('.');

                if (tokens[1] == "pdf")
                {
                    var Ocr = new AdvancedOcr()
                    {
                        CleanBackgroundNoise = false,
                        ColorDepth = 4,
                        ColorSpace = AdvancedOcr.OcrColorSpace.Color,
                        EnhanceContrast = false,
                        DetectWhiteTextOnDarkBackgrounds = false,
                        RotateAndStraighten = false,
                        Language = IronOcr.Languages.English.OcrLanguagePack,
                        EnhanceResolution = false,
                        InputImageType = AdvancedOcr.InputTypes.Document,
                        ReadBarCodes = true,
                        Strategy = AdvancedOcr.OcrStrategy.Fast
                    };

                    var Results = Ocr.ReadPdf(filepath);
                    var Pages = Results.Pages;
                    var FullPdfText = Results.Text;
                    FullPdfText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullPdfText).ToString();
                    FullPdfText = "<p>" + FullPdfText;
                    FullPdfText = FullPdfText.Replace("\r\n", @"</p><p>");
                    FullPdfText = FullPdfText.Replace("\r", "<\r>");
                    ViewData["FileViewer"] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullPdfText);
                    return Content(FullPdfText);
                }
                else
                {
                    var Ocr = new AutoOcr();
                    var Result = Ocr.Read(filepath);
                    return Content(Result.Text);
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This code works fine when you run simply on visual studio.But when you host the entire solution to IIS , it throws an exception , "IronOcr.ReadPdf - could not extract images from PDF, it may be encrypted ,not a valid PDF document, or you may have insufficient file permissions:" for pdf files.
And for image file conversion it show the following error - "The type initializer for 'NativeMagickSettings' threw an exception."This library seems to be paid, but am using a trial or demo version,could this be the reason?

Comment: Hello, IronOCR is a paid library, when it is running on a release mode  it raises an exception. Maybe this is something you can look into.

Comment: atleast they should have added a proper message.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: It throws the same error when running in VS2019 with NetCore. Using .NetFramework 4.7.1, it worked fine.